# Code cleanup/reformatting not applying styles to existing code

Tags: rider

I'm new to Jetbeans & Rider in general.

I've loaded my project into Rider, and so far things have been good. I like the warnings it comes up to enforce style/standards (similar to linting I've used with typescript).

However, I'd built a lot of the code in Visual Studio, and used slightly different styles (for example, private fields were just lower case, not prefixed with `_`).

I ran a solution wide reformat, and code-cleanup. Both, however, simply re-arranged the ordering of my methods/fields. It applied some newer language features like using `=>` for single line getters etc. It also did some great formatting/standardizing of curly braces. However there are still a good few hundred issues/warnings.

However, there's still hundreds of style warnings on all my files - it didn't rename any fields with `_`, it also didn't follow the white-space rules (the fields seem all randomly scattered with blank lines) and it's now really messy. While the warnings are great for new code, the existing code has far too many to do manually.

Is there any way to apply the styles, or force the clean-up to apply them? Even if it sorted out the blank line spacing I'd be happy!

Edit: I've found I can 'fix all' with some problems (like `_` naming), but it seems random what you can fix all on, or what you have to go through every single offending line for. For example, redundant xaml resources, you can only 'fix all' for the file, not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you go `Settings -> Editor -> Code Cleanup` you can see the options that code cleanup offers. Renaming unfortunatelly is not one of them, also remove redundant XAML sources. But as you allready figured out, the renaming process can be done for the whole solution as a quick fix. That is the only thing you can do, as far as I am concerned. Not perfect, but better than in Visual Studio ;)